# Java - SOAP for high traffic

Tags: java, performance, web-services, soap

Me and my team will implement a SOAP WS that will receive near 15 millions requests/day. This WS will call another WS (this process takes something like 6 seconds) and will return the result of request.

I was wondering if SOAP can handle it without a huge delay. Is it possible? JAX-WS is the best choice to implement it? If not, what are the other options that i have?

Thanks!

Comment: use cache. Have a look at Guava or Terracotta

Comment: Are you aware that there'll be `6*15e6/86400`, i.e. over 1000 pending requests *on the average*? This means either >1000 threads (and the peak might be much higher) or asynchronous handling. AFAIK, SOAP is not exactly known for its low overhead.

Comment: If we use REST, we'll have the same problem, right? And about sockets? We are doing an integration with 2 services. Our client could open a socket connection and send a positional string. Is it a good idea?

Comment: "we'll have the same problem" -- yes, but you'd have to try hard to get as much overhead as SOAP offers. A tailor-made solution may be a good idea as long as the communication is really simple. Consider adding some more details to your question to get more attention.